# Create a modal in hugo with bootstrap v4.6

Tags: html, jquery, css, hugo

I state that I'm not very familiar with web programming and in particular with how Hugo's templeting works, so sorry if I use the wrong terminology. I am creating my website based on a Hugo theme and I would like to do some customizations.

Precisely I would like to change the layout of a section of this theme to make it in a lightbox style where by default only images are shown as a gallery, which in my case would represent the single projects that I would like to share online, and then create a modal that should activate when the user clicks on one of the images in the section. This modal should show the same image on the left side and some text (project title, summary and a button link) on the right.

Researching I discovered that this theme uses bootstrap v4.6.0, so despite my lack of knowledge, I created a reproducible example of what the page's behavior should be.

I cannot share the code of the theme page I'm interested in because it is a list page rendered through hugo code to extract the parameters from the Yalm of the different projects that are saved on separate folders and with different `.md` files, so it would not give any output, unless I share the whole site or theme, and also sadly I have not yet deployed my site on any hosting service.

Below is the example code. For the moment I have overlooked defining a style to make the modal layout as I would like because the most important thing is to make it work with the hugo code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Gallery Modal</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">

.img-responsive{
    margin: 8px;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}   

.img-responsive:hover{
    box-shadow: 4px 5px 5px 4px #888888;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.heading{
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 35px;
   
}

.btn-info{
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
  bottom: 0;
}
p{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: left;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.modal-body img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.modal-body button {
  margin-top: auto;
}



</style>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="heading">Portfolio</h2>  
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href=""  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-1">
          <div>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1497206365907-f5e630693df0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=580&q=80" class="img-responsive img-rounded" width="100%" height="100%">
          </div>
        </a>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal-1" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
          
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header" style="border-bottom: none; height: 1rem;">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body" style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">

                <div style="max-width: 50%;">
                  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1497206365907-f5e630693df0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=580&q=80">
                </div>
                
                <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 50%; padding-left: 2rem; align-items: center;">
                  <h2 class="modal-title">Project Title</h2>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation</p>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">View Project</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href=""  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-2">
          <div>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589656966895-2f33e7653819?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80" class="img-responsive img-rounded" width="100%" height="100%">
          </div>
        </a>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal-2" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
          
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header" style="border-bottom: none; height: 1rem;">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body" style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">

                <div style="max-width: 50%;">
                  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589656966895-2f33e7653819?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80">
                </div>
                
                <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 50%; padding-left: 2rem; align-items: center;">
                  <h2 class="modal-title">Project Title</h2>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation</p>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">View Project</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href=""  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-3">
          <div>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1591824438708-ce405f36ba3d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=387&q=80" class="img-responsive img-rounded" width="100%" height="100%">
          </div>
        </a>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal-3" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
          
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header" style="border-bottom: none; height: 1rem;">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body" style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">

                <div style="max-width: 50%;">
                  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1591824438708-ce405f36ba3d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=387&q=80">
                </div>
                
                <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 50%; padding-left: 2rem; align-items: center;">
                  <h2 class="modal-title">Project Title</h2>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation</p>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">View Project</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href=""  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-4">
          <div>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1574870111867-089730e5a72b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=387&q=80" class="img-responsive img-rounded" width="100%" height="100%">
          </div>
        </a>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal-4" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
          
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header" style="border-bottom: none; height: 1rem;">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body" style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">

                <div style="max-width: 50%;">
                  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1574870111867-089730e5a72b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=387&q=80">
                </div>
                
                <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 50%; padding-left: 2rem; align-items: center;">
                  <h2 class="modal-title">Project Title</h2>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation</p>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">View Project</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>



      <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href=""  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-5">
          <div>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1564349683136-77e08dba1ef7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=872&q=80" class="img-responsive img-rounded" width="100%" height="100%">
          </div>
        </a>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal-5" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
          
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header" style="border-bottom: none; height: 1rem;">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body" style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">

                <div style="max-width: 50%;">
                  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1564349683136-77e08dba1ef7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=872&q=80">
                </div>
                
                <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 50%; padding-left: 2rem; align-items: center;">
                  <h2 class="modal-title">Project Title</h2>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation</p>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">View Project</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href=""  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-6">
          <div>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1484406566174-9da000fda645?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=389&q=80" class="img-responsive img-rounded" width="100%" height="100%">
          </div>
        </a>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal-6" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
          
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header" style="border-bottom: none; height: 1rem;">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body" style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">

                <div style="max-width: 50%;">
                  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1484406566174-9da000fda645?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=389&q=80">
                </div>
                
                <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 50%; padding-left: 2rem; align-items: center;">
                  <h2 class="modal-title">Project Title</h2>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation</p>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">View Project</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>






      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, using only html you need to create a modal for each image, but in a Hugo template this should be done iteratively. I don't know how to tell Hugo that for each image, the modal that appears after the click must show the information of that related project (image, title, summary and link of the button).

So far I have managed to get the image to work by using

```
{{ $item := .item }}
{{ $resource := ($item.Resources.ByType "image").GetMatch "*featured*" }}
    
{{ with $resource }}
{{ $image := .Resize "600x" }}
<img src="{{ $image.RelPermalink }}" alt="{{ $item.Title }}">
{{ end }}
```

but I can't do the same with the text.

I know I could directly ask the creator of the theme as they suggested in previous comments, but if someone could help me, even with a generalized example, I would gladly appreciate it.

EDIT:

The site is structured as follows:

```
.
├── assets
├── config
├── content/
│   ├── home/
│   │   ├── index.md
│   │   ├── widget1.md
│   │   ├── portfolio.md
│   │   └── other-widjets.md
│   └── project/
│       ├── project1/
│       │   ├── index.md
│       │   └── featured.png
│       ├── project2/
│       │   ├── index.md
│       │   └── featured.jpg
│       └── other-projects
├── data
├── layouts/ (to override the layout of themes)
│   ├── _default
│   ├── partials/
│   │   ├── widgets/
│   │   │   └── portfolio.html (it uses view/masonry.html to list projects)
│   │   └── views/
│   │       ├── masonry.html (for potfolio.html, I'M CUSTOMIZING IT)
│   │       └── other-views.html
│   ├── project/
│   │   └── single.html (layout for project/index.md)
│   └── other-folders-and-files
├── other-folders
└── themes
```

If it helps, these are the layouts of the html files used by default in the theme:

- [partials/widgets/portfolio.html](https://github.com/wowchemy/wowchemy-hugo-themes/blob/main/wowchemy/layouts/partials/widgets/portfolio.html)
- [partials/views/masonry.html](https://github.com/wowchemy/wowchemy-hugo-themes/blob/main/wowchemy/layouts/partials/views/masonry.html)
- [layouts/project/single.html](https://github.com/wowchemy/wowchemy-hugo-themes/blob/main/wowchemy/layouts/project/single.html)

In the yalm/frontmatter of the portfolio.md file is defined the parameter `view: '3'` which calls the layout views/masonry.html

Instead, the parameters considered for the single projects, which are then shown in the masonry, are

```
---
title: Project Title
summary: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et pain magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation

# Featured image
# To use, add an image named `featured.jpg/png` to your page's folder.
image:
   caption: example of a caption

# Button
links:
- name: View Project
  url: http://example.org
---

Project contents ...
```

**I think that in order to make the modal work it is necessary to specify, via hugo code, the reference using the `data-target` and `id` attributes inside the tags** `<a href=""  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-1">` and `<div class="modal fade" id="myModal-1" role="dialog">` respectively

For example, considering the first image and the respective modal, they have in common the reference `myModal-1`:

```
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href=""  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-1">
          <div>
            <img src="..." class="img-responsive img-rounded" width="100%" height="100%">
          </div>
        </a>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal-1" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
          
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: So, this isn't a Hugo question per se'. You are heavily editing a theme to get a feature added. The question would be to the creator of the theme on their issues/discussions boards. I.e. "I want this feature in your theme, how do I do it/can you do it?" Make sense? The only way to answer your question is to download Academic and do what you are saying and come up with a solution to add this. Due to the way you've worded and requested assistance (which is to debug your code) you might not get an answer... I don't mean this to be rude, but to give assistance to ask the better question, no?

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I apologize if I write so late. As you rightly pointed out to me, it would be best to ask the issue directly to the theme developer. I thought it was not necessary to download the template to get an answer to my problem and that the output I got was just a mistake/oversight with the hugo code when defining the attributes inside the tags, which therefore do not make the javascript work. Thanks anyway for your suggestions.

Comment: Ah, Kechiring...
May I make a suggestion? Why don't you edit your question to ask what you put in this comment? That is a question that could be answered... i.e. defining attributes inside tags (I mean, make it more clear than that...) but there you can be assisted...

Comment: I hope it's not too late, however I tried to edit my post, giving a reproducible example code and explaining the problem better. In these days I did some more detailed research and I discovered that the academic theme uses bootstrap which by default offers a modal component that I can use instead of creating one from scratch and making mistakes ... I apologize for not being very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Going to need more information, but for the sake of dialogues I'm going to distill your post to the question:
"As you can see, using only html you need to create a modal for each image, but in a Hugo template this should be done iteratively. I don't know how to tell Hugo that for each image, the modal that appears after the click must show the information of that related project (image, title, summary and link of the button)."

Three ways that I know of to do this:

1. Data file
2. Front matter of markdown
   2a. Each image gets it's own markdown file.
   or 2b. If their is some other heirachy, then a heirarchy of images in a markdown file.

For a datafile, create a json/toml/yaml file - but it in the Data folder of Hugo.

You can then range over the the image using the standard syntax:
(The example in the docs)
data/jazz/bass/jacopastorius.toml <- file
(Example of what is in file:

```
{  
  "discography": [  
      "1974 - Jaco",  
   ]  
}
```

data/jazz/bass/johnpatitucci.toml <- file2 (though you can just   do 1 big file as I often do).
How to access the info in the toml file

```
{{ range $.Site.Data.jazz.bass }}  
   {{ partial "artist.html" . }} <- Takes the info from your TOML and makes it accesible to your partial  
{{ end }}
```

So instead of Jazz musicians you would have image paths and their meta data.
That partial would have your code you speak about in reference to bootstrap.
In case this becomes your next question: the "dot" "." at the end passes the context. So that means in your partial you can access the context of whatever context you are in. So in the above example you could access .discography from the partial. Get it?

You would do similar from front matter, but that you can figure out from docs.

Let me know if that helps.

If you want the docs page which I find very helpful (more so than my explanation): https://gohugo.io/templates/data-templates/

You could also do this via pages, other methods, but I would, well, I don't know what these images are relative to other things nor your site hierarchy, but the above is a workable method that if you experiment with, will lend to understanding Hugo more and I'm sure you can come up with more specific solutions.

Note: If you are getting this image for a variety of markdown pages, then range the .Site.Pages variable, and use a where statement for whatever filter is required to get the specific markdown pages you need.

Al la:

```
{{ range where .Site.Pages ".Params.images" "WHATEVER VALUE HERE" }}
  {{.items }} <- just an example, I'm unsure of what specific front matter you would need.
{{ end }}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for your patience. I have considered your suggestions for extracting data from the front matter of individual projects, but I think that to make the modal work well you need to use suitable ugo code in the tag attributes `data-target` and` id`.
You're right, I re-edited my post to give more information on the structure of the theme and explaining the problem of the reference in the tag attributes that I forgot to mention.